# SonarQube 5.1.1 and Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sonarqube

Hello I'm trying to install SonarQube 5.1.1 with Oracle XE 11g DB.
I've performed the requirements steps:

1. Create the database user with
   `CREATE USER sonar IDENTIFIED BY sonar;
   GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, CONNECT, RESOURCE, CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE SEQUENCE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TRIGGER TO sonar;
   EXIT`
2. Download ojdbc6.jar from Oracle's download site and place it in `/opt/sonarqube-5.1.1/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle`
3. Change the conf\sonar.properties as follow: 
   comment out:
   `sonar.jdbc.url: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sonar;create=true`
4. remove comment from:
   `sonar.jdbc.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE
   sonar.jdbc.driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
   sonar.jdbc.validationQuery: select 1 from dual`
5. Start the SonarQube server with `./sonar.sh start`

The console doesn't work.

When I try to launch the console through ./sonar.sh console I get back the following message.

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2015.07.09 10:51:15 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.1.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process5315721777324339581properties
jvm 1    | 2015.07.09 10:51:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
jvm 1    | 2015.07.09 10:51:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-5.1.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube-5.1.1/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle/ojdbc6.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process6137893542254624184properties
jvm 1    | 2015.07.09 10:53:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2015.07.09 10:53:53 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: We don't understand **doesn't work**. Please provide more information.

Comment: When I type http://localhost:9000 on the browser I don't get back any response.

Comment: Can you have a look at logs/ please ?

Comment: Hello @Simon , I've noticed that now SonarQube is working fine.<br/>  I've added the database port `1521` to the connection string.  Anyway the uncommented lines on the conf .properties file are: 1. db user; 2. db password; 3. db connection string; 4. sonar.web.context=/sonar; 5. sonar.web.port=9000. Is this the right configuration for a default installation?

Comment: The db settings are prefixed by sonar.jdbc. But as I said please check the logs to better understand the bad configuration.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource: you're right. I've found this message in the log file `2015.07.09 10:49:56 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Simon I looked to sonar.log file and I found that the sonar jdbc driver need `hostname:port\sid`, so I missing the port information. I changed the conf file in that way and now it properly works.